# Gorm executes SELECT * FROM tablename but it also does WHERE "tablename"."id"=0; Which returns no record found

Tags: go, go-gorm

[image]I am trying to make a simple blog API in Go.

This is my struct

```golang
type Blog struct {
    Id     int    `gorm:"primary key" json:"id"`
    Author string `gorm:"type:varchar(100);not null" json:"author"`
    Title  string `gorm:"type:varchar(1000);not null" json:"title"`
    Body   string `gorm:"size:1000;not null" json:"body"`
}
```

all the other create get methods work except the get all method

```golang
func (b *Blog) GetAll(db *gorm.DB) (*[]Blog, error){
    var blogs  []Blog
    records := db.Find(&blogs)
    if records.Error != nil{
        return &[]Blog{}, records.Error
    }
    return &blogs, nil
}
```

This method executes this query as seen in debug output

```sql
SELECT * FROM "blogs" WHERE "blogs"."id" = 0 ORDER BY "blogs"."id" LIMIT 1
```

Which will obviously return nothing

I have tried finding on the docs but the docs suggest i do it like this only... and noone on stackoverflow has had this problem

Comment: can you double check if you used db.Find , it look that you have used db.First instead.

Comment: @prembhaskal check the image thats my code i used db.Find i dont know why its still doing that pretty wierd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i found what was going wrong
[image]

These were my routes
since the route /blog/{id} was defined first if i made a get request to /get/all
it would default to /blog/id and take all as id  and when it converts to int it would error thus using id = 0 and giving me nothing

So to fix this i just had to change my route

Like this :
[image]

I hope someone would learn from my stupid mistake :>

Comment: Please try to use text next time around. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @mkopriva i used code in a markdown format but since someone asked if i did the same thing in my IDE that is why i pasted a picture please read the question and then reply i pasted the picture after...